# Trouble picking up package definitions

Tags: packages, scoping

I open a new notebook and type

```
ClearAll[test];
test[x_] := x + 42;
```

I save it as `Temp.nb` and *also* as `Temp.m`, using the menu *Save As... > Wolfram Mathematica Package (*.m)*. I now open up another notebook and type

```
<< "Temp.m"
```

which succeeds. But the symbol `test` is not defined.

```
?? test
```

> ```
> Information::notfound: Symbol test not found. >>
> ```

```
test[3]
```

> ```
> test[3]
> ```

I'm confused, because the documentation for `Get`, a.k.a., `<<`, says

> << name reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it and
>   returning the last one.

It should have evaluated the expressions in `Temp.m`, then, I should think, and returned the [value of] the last one, which would be `Null`.  One of those expressions is a `SetDelayed` for the symbol `test` and should have installed `test` in the Global namespace, no?

Fresh kernel session, fresh reboot of MMA, also fails if file is saved as *Wolfram Language Package (*.wl)*, yada yada.

Comment: Only initialization cells in `.m` files are evaluated when loaded.

Comment: More accurately only Initialization Cells are saved as active (non-comment) lines in the package file.